# Provide a list of subtypes from Main group with range numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, range

I have a table named Items containing a list of items both at grouped level (G) and sub level (L). However I want to see only the sub level (L) data but with the respective Group Name attached to each sublevel. The Grouped item has a start and end number range. The numbers are not +1 for the sub level list, but incremental in no particular fashion. Also for each level row the start and end number is same.

I am using Microsoft SQL-Server Management Studio-2018

Main table: **Items**

| Code | Start_No | End_No | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Group 1** | 1001 | 1035 | G |
| AA | 1001 | 1001 | L |
| BB | 1005 | 1005 | L |
| CC | 1009 | 1009 | L |
| DD | 1020 | 1020 | L |
| EE | 1035 | 1035 | L |
| **Group 2** | 1051 | 1090 | G |
| FF | 1051 | 1051 | L |
| GG | 1060 | 1060 | L |
| HH | 1075 | 1075 | L |
| JJ | 1090 | 1090 | L |
| **Group 3** | 1095 | 1200 | G |
| LL | 1095 | 1095 | L |
| OO | 1120 | 1120 | L |
| PP | 1200 | 1200 | L |
| **Group 4** | 1300 | 1800 | G |
| QQ | 1300 | 1300 | L |
| TU | 1500 | 1500 | L |
| WC | 1600 | 1600 | L |
| ZA | 1800 | 1800 | L |

I would like for the final output to be:

**Desired outcome**

| Code Group | Code | Start_No | End_No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | AA | 1001 | 1001 |
| Group 1 | BB | 1005 | 1005 |
| Group 1 | CC | 1009 | 1009 |
| Group 1 | DD | 1020 | 1020 |
| Group 1 | EE | 1035 | 1035 |
| Group 2 | FF | 1051 | 1051 |
| Group 2 | GG | 1060 | 1060 |
| Group 2 | HH | 1075 | 1075 |
| Group 2 | JJ | 1090 | 1090 |
| Group 3 | LL | 1095 | 1095 |
| Group 3 | OO | 1120 | 1120 |
| Group 3 | PP | 1200 | 1200 |
| Group 4 | QQ | 1300 | 1300 |
| Group 4 | TU | 1500 | 1500 |
| Group 4 | WC | 1600 | 1600 |
| Group 4 | ZA | 1800 | 1800 |

This is the code I have written but not getting desired result.

```
    Select i.Code, c.Start_No, c.End_No 
    into #temp
    FROM items i
    Where i.Type = 'L' 
    
    Select  i2.Code, i2.Start_No, i2.End_No 
    FROM GLM_CHART i2
    WHERE
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temp t where t.Start_No BETWEEN i2.Start_No AND i2.End_No)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `join`:

```
select i.*, ig.code
from items i join
     items ig
     on i.start_no >= ig.start_no and
        i.end_no <= ig.end_no and
        ig.type = 'G'
where i.type = 'L';
```

Comment: thanks for reordering the table format in the question. I believe you meant and ig.type = 'G' where i.type = 'L'; however the output is repeating the group names for each line of the sub rows instead of specific group name to its sub rows

Comment: Thanks the code worked. My data had an extra grouping layer that caused my initial confusion. Thanks once again.